# Login API in moodle angular 8

Tags: angular, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I need to login my user from my website to the moodle page.I have build function that create user and make enroll to course,Now i need to make auto login.

I have set the "moodle_mobile_app" that have return my token of the user ,but i can find any service that make the login.

I have all at my side `UserName,Password,Token` i just need some web service from moodle that can receive this data and return login Url

```
"/login/token.php?username=YOUR_FORM_USERNAME&password=YOUR_FORM_PASSWORD&service=moodle_mobile_app"
```

Do any one know the trick/way how can i make user be logged-in to mooble from my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this plugin that do the work

```
https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_userkey

https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-auth_userkey/blob/MOODLE_33PLUS/README.md
```

Download,and install it

Home -> Site administration -> Plugins -> Install plugins

Just drag your zip file with plugin that you have downloaded 
[image: Plugin install]

Set your plugin steps: your have full description [here](https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-auth_userkey/blob/MOODLE_33PLUS/README.md)

```
> 1.Install the plugin as usual.
> 2.Enable and configure just installed plugin. Set required Mapping field, User key life time, IP restriction and Logout redirect URL.
> 3.Enable web service advance feature (Admin > Advanced features), more info http://docs.moodle.org/en/Web_services
> 4.Enable one of the supported protocols (Admin > Plugins > Web services > Manage protocols)
> 5.Create a token for a specific user and for the service 'User key authentication web service' (Admin > Plugins > Web services > Manage
> tokens)
> 6.Make sure that the "web service" user has 'auth/userkey:generatekey' capability.
> 7.Configure your external application to make a web call to get login URL.
> 8.Redirect your users to this URL to be logged in to Moodle.
```

Then download  [sample-ws-clients](https://github.com/moodlehq/sample-ws-clients)

Unzip and ,add it to your root folder,then I have add file named sso.php
 to folder `Online.mydomain.com\sample-ws-clients-master\PHP-REST\sso.php`

My sso.php code that reciving email,and returm login url back to you

```
<?php

/**
 * @param   string $useremail Email address of user to create token for.
 * @param   string $firstname First name of user (used to update/create user).
 * @param   string $lastname Last name of user (used to update/create user).
 * @param   string $username Username of user (used to update/create user).
 * @param   string $ipaddress IP address of end user that login request will come from (probably $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).
 * @param int      $courseid Course id to send logged in users to, defaults to site home.
 * @param int      $modname Name of course module to send users to, defaults to none.
 * @param int      $activityid cmid to send logged in users to, defaults to site home.
 * @return bool|string
 */

 $userEmail = $_GET["email"];
 $courseid = $_GET["id"];


function getloginurl($useremail, $courseid) {
    require_once('./curl.php');


    $token        = 'your token';
    $domainname   = 'your domain';
    $functionname = 'auth_userkey_request_login_url';


    $param = [
        'user' => [
            'username'  => $useremail
        ] 
    ]; 

    $serverurl = $domainname . '/webservice/rest/server.php' . '?wstoken=' . $token . '&wsfunction=' . $functionname . '&moodlewsrestformat=json';
    $curl = new curl; // The required library curl can be obtained from https://github.com/moodlehq/sample-ws-clients 

    try {
        $resp     = $curl->post($serverurl, $param);
        $resp     = json_decode($resp);


        if ($resp && !empty($resp->loginurl)) {
            $loginurl = $resp->loginurl; 


        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!isset($loginurl)) {

        return false;
    }

    $path = '';
    if (isset($courseid)) {

        $path = '&wantsurl=' . $domainname . '/course/view.php?id=' . $courseid;
    }
    if (isset($modname) && isset($activityid)) {
        $path = '&wantsurl=' . urlencode("$domainname/mod/$modname/view.php?id=$activityid");
    }


    echo $loginurl . $path;
    header('Location:' . $loginurl . $path);
    return $loginurl . $path;
}

getloginurl($userEmail, $courseid);
```